# Prove that $\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}<e^n<\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n!}$

Tags: calculus

I've already proven that $\forall x \in ]0,+\infty[$ $(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$$<e<(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+1}$ 
but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: At first glance this suggests to me that the $n!$ should move to join the $e^n$ and an $n^n$ term should take its place...

Answer (score 2):

For $0<x<1$ we have $x=\int_{1-x}^11dt<\int_{1-x}^1(1/t)dt =-\ln (1-x).$ From this, for $n\in \Bbb N$ we obtain $$(1)...\quad\frac {1}{n+2}<-\ln \frac {n+1}{n+2}=\ln \frac {n+2}{n+1}.$$

For $y>1$ we have $y=\int_1^{1+y}1dt>\int_1^{1+y}(1/t)dt=\ln (1+y).$ From this, for $n\in \Bbb N$ we obtain $$(2)... \quad \frac {1}{n+1}>\ln \frac{n+2}{n+1}.$$

Now we use induction.

Base: We have $(1+1)^1/1!=2<e<4=(1+1)^2/1!.$

For the left inequality we have $(n+1)^n/n!<e\iff n\ln (n+1)<1+\ln n!$

Let $A(n)=n\ln (n+1)$ and $B(n)=1+\ln n!.$

Now IF $A(n+1)-A(n)<B(n+1)-B(n)$ THEN $A(n)<B(n)\implies A(n+1)<B(n+1).$

And when you explicitly calculate $A(n+1)-A(n)$ and $B(n+1)-B(n)$  you find that $A(n+1)-A(n)<B(n+1)-B(n) \iff \ln \frac {n+2}{n+1}<\frac {1}{n+1},$ which is (2).

Similarly for the right inequality, where the inductive step is shown to be implied by (1).

Answer (score 0):

Proceed by induction on $n$. You'll want to use the inequality you already derived with $x  = n+1$.